# Example 1 Sec 13 in Munkres TOPOLOGY: A sphere contained in the intersection of spheres

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $r_1, \ldots, r_m$ be given positive real numbers; for each $i=1, \ldots, m$,  let $(x_{i1}, \ldots, x_{in})$ be $m$ given points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let 
$$S_i \colon= \left\{ \ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \colon \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n (x_j - x_{ij})^2} < r_i \ \right\}.$$

Finally, let 
$$S \colon= \bigcap_{i=1}^m S_i.$$

Then

(1) What is (are ) the necessary and sufficient condition(s) --- on the $x_{ij}$, $y_{ij}$, and $r_i$ --- for the intersection set $S$ to be non-empty?

Comment: Let $y_i=(x_{i1},\ldots,x_{in}).$ 

Would it suffice $d(y_i,y_j)<\underset{i,j}{\min}{r_i+r_j}$ $\forall i\neq j$ where $d$ is euclidean metric?

Comment: @Suhail your comment isn't clear enough, I'm afraid.